# Can't figure out how to add polymorphic tags in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a sample rails app with a list of users. And I wanted to experiment with polymorphic tags.

At this moment I can create tags for users through console in the following way
`User.first.tags.create(name: "new tag name")`

But have problems with adding them through webform

Here's what I did:

```
rails g model Tag name taggable:references{polymorphic}
```

generated the following migration

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :taggable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

tag model

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
end
```

Tags field

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :tag_list %>
    <%= form.text_field :tag_list, placeholder: "tags separated by comma" %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

I also found the following code but getting `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved` error.

added the following setter to user model and added `:tag_list` to strong params of user

```
  def tag_list=(vals)
    self.tags = vals.split(", ").each do |val|
      tags.where(name: val.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add tags with nested form

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags 
end
```

in your form

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  ...
 <div class="field">
    <% form.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
      <%= u.text_field :tag_name %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

in your controller , please add other attribute as well

```
params.require(:user).permit( tags_attributes: [:id,:tag_name])
```